# notepad++ sorting lines by dates

Tags: sorting, notepad++

I need to sort lines by date

I'm trying to turn this:

```
15.01.2023 19:50:aksnlasfnl
24.03.2023 19:50:asdkabskdbj
17.01.2023 19:50:97gouasoisda
16.04.2023 19:50:sadibk28
01.05.2023 19:50:a7sgdajdhsj
```

into this:

```
15.01.2023 19:50:aksnlasfnl
17.01.2023 19:50:97gouasoisda
24.03.2023 19:50:asdkabskdbj
16.04.2023 19:50:sadibk28
01.05.2023 19:50:a7sgdajdhsj
```

date format being dd.mm.yy

tried sorting by line operations and it sorted by days only, ignoring months

Comment: You'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression search+replace to convert the dates to ISO format (`yyyy-mm-dd`). Then sorting by date is the same as sorting lexicographically, which Notepad++ supports out of the box.

So replacing `^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})` by `\3-\2-\1` and then sorting alphabetically should work. If you need the original date format, you can change it back by replacing `^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})` by `\3.\2.\1`.

This only works assuming that in the original file there are no lines that have something that looks like an ISO date at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Using gawk you can to:

```
D:\TEMP>type sort.txt
15.01.2023 19:50:aksnlasfnl
24.03.2023 19:50:asdkabskdbj
17.01.2023 19:50:97gouasoisda
16.04.2023 19:50:sadibk28
01.05.2023 19:50:a7sgdajdhsj
D:\TEMP>gawk -F "[. ]" "{ s=$3$2$1; a[s]=$0 }END{ for(i in a) { print a[i]}; }" sort.txt
15.01.2023 19:50:aksnlasfnl
17.01.2023 19:50:97gouasoisda
24.03.2023 19:50:asdkabskdbj
16.04.2023 19:50:sadibk28
01.05.2023 19:50:a7sgdajdhsj

D:\TEMP>
```

A short explanation

- The input file is read line by line, separated by a "." (dot) or a " " (space).
- The first column (day) will be stored in `$1`
- The second column (day) will be stored in `$2`
- The third column (day) will be stored in `$3`
- The complete record ($0) will be stored in the array `a`, using a key which build as `YYYYMMDD` (`20230115` for the first line)
- The `end` section prints the array, in the order of the key.

gawk can be installed using [choco](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/gawk): `choco install gawk`

Comment: I didn't have to use gawk, but thank you for putting an effort!